# ARKit: Rendering multiple anchors and nodes in didUpdate method

Tags: swift, arkit, renderer, aranchor

Trying to update two different nodes in renderer(_ renderer:didUpdate:for:) method for different anchors
looks like it let me update only one node, but I needed both:
ARFaceAnchor and ARMeshAnchor
How can I solve this problem?

```
// 1
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor ) {
        if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor {
            targetFaceGeometry = faceAnchor.geometry
        }
    }
```

&

```
// 2
   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor ) {
        if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
            let geometry = createGeometryFromAnchor(meshAnchor: meshAnchor)
            geometry.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = [.alpha]
            node.geometry = geometry
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle both cases in a single function

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor {
        targetFaceGeometry = faceAnchor.geometry
    } else if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
        let geometry = createGeometryFromAnchor(meshAnchor: meshAnchor)
        geometry.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = [.alpha]
        node.geometry = geometry
    }
}
```